# How to discard faulted messages when using the ConfigureEndpoints method in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

[This article](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#error-pipe) provides an example of how to do this when configuring an endpoint manually.

Just like this:

```cs
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("input-queue", ec =>
{
    ec.DiscardFaultedMessages();
});
```

But I've got a lot of consumers and I don't want to configure each of them manually, so I use methods `AddConsumers` and `ConfigureEndpoints`.
Like this:

```cs
    services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            cfg.AddBus(sp => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => x.ConfigureEndpoints(sp)));
        });
```

If I additionally call the `ReceiveEndPoint` method (before or after calling `ConfigureEndpoints`), the exception "A receive endpoint with the same key was already added" is thrown.

Is there a way to configure a specific endpoint when using ConfigureEndpoints method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `ConfigureEndpoints`, consumers, sagas, and activites are configured on receive endpoints automatically. To configure the receive endpoint for a specific consumer, create a [consumer definition](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/definitions.html). If scanning an assembly for consumers, matching consumer definitions will also be discovered.

```
public class SubmitOrderConsumerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<SubmitOrderConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<SubmitOrderConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {        
        endpointConfigurator.DiscardFaultedMessage();
    }
}
```